# Unable to set custom background colour of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make the background colour of my ActionBar a colour corresponding to the code. For some reason my app crashes when it reaches this line of code.

```
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3f9845")));
```

When I remove it the error goes (ActionBar background is set to black by default). I've tried rearranging the line to be above and below

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_register1);
```

but still no luck.

This is the theme I'm using if it has any relevance

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> </style>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Post your stacktrace! Any reason you do not want to set it in the style? This is how it is commonly done ..

Comment: Can you show me how to do it in the style?

Comment: added an answer with the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AppCompat, you need to call getSupportActionBar() instead.

If you want to change the color by style with the recent versions of AppCompat, you just need to set the "colorPrimary" attribute in your theme to the color you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can set it in the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_action_bar_color</item>
</style>
```